# How can I transfer a compiled tuple(rawly taken from Sql) in to a array, series, or a dataframe?

Tags: python, mysql

1. What I have is like this:

   ```
   (('3177000000000053', '8018000000000498', datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 29, 21, 36, 42)), 
    ('3177000000000035', '8018000000000498', datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 29, 21, 37, 6 )))
   ```

It is exactly the way it looks in mysql database.

2. What I want is like this:

   ```
   [[1,2,3],
   [4,5,6]]
   ```

It's okay to have a series, dataframe, array, list.etc. I just want it to be managable for further analysing process.
I've tried several ways to deal with this such as dataframe(),list(),even pandas.replace(and it gives me a tuple-cant-be-replaced error).
I'm new to python, thanks for your answers!:)))))))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have tuple of tuples you may try the following list comprehension

```
import datetime

input_tuple = (('3177000000000053', '8018000000000498', datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 29, 21, 36, 42)),
 ('3177000000000035', '8018000000000498', datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 29, 21, 37, 6 )))

output_list = [[i for i in j] for j in input_tuple]

print(output_list)
```

Comment: Спасибо!! it helps a lot!